# Using Python's struct library to pack None type

Tags: python, struct

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("!x", None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: pack expected 0 items for packing (got 1)
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), the `x` format character acts as a pad byte in C which translates to a 'no value' type in Python or `None`. But I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: What would you expect to be the output here?

Comment: I thought it'd be `b'\x00'`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This seems like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) issue.

Comment: You don't need to provide any value for the `x` format character.

Comment: Why would something with no value have the value `\x00`? :)

Comment: @Nissal `None` is not equivalent to the null byte. Python != C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "no value" means do not put a value, not that `None` needs to be specified.

```py
>>> struct.pack("!x")
'\x00'
```

Likewise, when unpacking a struct, `x` will effectively cause that byte to be skipped.

```py
>>> struct.unpack("!x", '\x00')
()
```